# How do you e-mail a webpage to yourself?

Tags: email, website, html, webpage

Is it possible to e-mail a webpage to e-mail address. I dont mean the link of a page. I mean the actual webpage in html forms so that the webpage can be viewed in an e-mail.

Comment: Did a Google search and can able to find a lot like this :)

Answer (score 3):

In IE8 : Page -> Send Page by Email ...

Firefox : Use the add-on [Send Page By Email](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2343).

Some of these might not work, depending on your mixture of browser/mail-client.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Microsoft Outlook 2000, Microsoft Outlook 2002, or Microsoft Office Outlook 2003 with Microsoft Internet Explorer, you can send a viewable Web page with active links to others who use Outlook, Microsoft Outlook Express, or other HTML-aware e-mail programs.